# How to fix ''Method 'StartAsync' in type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelServer' does not have an implementation.''

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a webapplication project in MVC, I am using VS2017, I started the project by .net framework 4.5
In the middle of work I understood that I have to use .net framework 4.6
after upgrading the framework I see this error when I ran the project.
(before upgrading the .net frame work I also upgrade .netcore 1.1 to .netCore 2.1)

error message is :

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'StartAsync' in type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelServer' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.'

The error accure in program class

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version do you use now?.net framework 4.6 or .net core2.1?You may need to upgrade your packages version (1.1.1.0) to match  your current project version.

Comment: Thanks for your response Xing Zou, Actually I solved the problem by migrate my project into .net core 2.0.0 Using this Link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-3.0. As I understand .net framework 4.5 Is not compatible with .net core 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem

As I start my project with .net framework 4.5 and .net core 1.1.0 the project had some limitations, when I update .net framework to 4.6.1 the problem happens couse its not compatible with .net core 1.1.0 , after updating .net core to 2.0.0 I had some problems in classes like startup.cs and so on.

Finally I found this link that helped me to migrate from .net core 1.1.0 to .net core 2.0.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-3.0